# List all available networks connected to windows

Tags: c, networking

I want a list of all the connected networks to my pc. consider my computer has 3 active internet connections i.e. Ethernet,WiFi and USB dongle .How can I list these connections in my application. I am using C language in my application.
Secondly, can I use all these active connections simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The following c program gives the network connections in your system.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<netdb.h>
int main()
{

        struct netent *networks;
        setnetent(1);
        while((networks = getnetent()) != NULL)
        {
                printf("%s\n",networks->n_name);
        }
        endnetent();

}
```

The getnetent function is used to get the network entry in the /etc/networks file.
The structure netent is defined in the netdb.h header file.
For more information read the man page for getnetent function.
I hope this will help you.